# How to override CSS being applied via Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

A JS file (that I am not allowed to edit) is applying inline CSS `display: flex !important` to a `div`. How do I override it to `display: none` ?

[image]

I have tried the following without success:

CSS:

```
.ui.page.modals.dimmer.transition.visible.active {
    display: none !important;
}

.ui.page.modals.dimmer.transition.visible.active[style] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("div.ui.page.modals.dimmer.transition.visible.active").css("display","none");
```

Comment: `display: flex !important` is being applied in real-time when the modal becomes active and my jQuery applies on page load. So mine gets overridden.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include information; comments are not a good place for relevant information. Also, please include code as text, not as an image of text.

Comment: The second version, using the `[style]` attribute selector, should work for this (https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/) If it doesn’t for you - then we need a proper [mre].

Answer (score 0):

if you add !important and the js couldn't allow you to override it, you can simply do following steps:
1. try to remove attribute style using js like -

```
$("div.ui.page.modals.dimmer.transition.visible.active").removeAttr('style');
```

2. once you remove the style attribute simply add -

```
$("div.ui.page.modals.dimmer.transition.visible.active").css("display","none");
```

try it works for me all time. I hope this will help you.

Make sure to add this js after the script which you can't edit is loaded.

Comment: That didn't work. I think because `display: flex !important` is being applied in real-time when the modal becomes active and our jQuery applies once on page load. So ours get overridden.

Comment: is display flex comes by calling active class in js. if yes the try this:
$("div.ui.page.modals.dimmer.transition.visible.active").removeClass('active');

Comment: You need a listener for when the modal is created. is there some event that causes the modal to be instantiated? ie an ajax call or a button click? figure out what is calling it and attach the code above to it after it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this a different way you could try wrapping the offending modal element in another element and making the wrapping element `display:none`.

It doesn't matter what the display property is of a child component if the parent is not displayed.

I believe the jQuery syntax would look something like this:

```
$('div.ui.page.modals.dimmer.transition.visible.active').wrap('<div style="display:none"></div>');
```

See https://api.jquery.com/wrap/